# Rewrite sympy equations to 0 right hand side

Tags: sympy

Does anyone know how I can rewrite all sympy equations to have zero right hand side?

I have a list of equations, each a string, that I would like to feed into "linear_eq_to_matrix".
My list looks somehting like

```
eqs = ['x+y =2', 'x = y']
```

In order to use "linear_eq_to_matrix", I need 2 things:

1. Reformulate the equations to have zero right hand side.
2. Change the string format of the equations. This can be done with sympy.sympify.

My code needs to look something like

```
eqns = [x + y - 2, 
        x - y]
A, b = linear_eq_to_matrix(eqns, [x, y])
```

I am not sure how to perform 1) above in order to get "eqns".

edit: I found out how to transform a string to a sympy expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it:

```
eqsString = ['x+y =2', 'x = y']
eqs = [sym.Eq(*map(sym.sympify, eq.split('='))) for eq in eqsString]
x, y = symbols('x, y')
A, b = linear_eq_to_matrix(eqs, [x, y])
A, b
```

Which gives

```
(Matrix([
 [1,  1],
 [1, -1]]), Matrix([
 [2],
 [0]]))
```